# Space between ticks marks and X axis with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am working on a simple canvas with Chart.js (version 3.x) that simply displays an evolution of price. The X axis is used for the time and the Y axis for the percentage of evolution. I have managed to do this but now, I would like to add a bit of style.

My objective is to add some space between the mark ticks and the X axis.

I have used the chart.js [styling documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.2/axes/styling.html) to help me, but I did not found anything that worked how I want.

Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA0L1.png) that I have and the associated code :

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('priceEvolutionChart');
const priceEvolutionChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: '#C4D3E4',
        borderColor: '#1C3452',
        tension: 0.1,
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: { display: false },
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          color: '#1C3452',
          callback(value) {
            return value + ' %';
          },
          font: {
            size: 16,
          },
        },
      },
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'quarter',
          displayFormats: {
            quarter: 'YYYY',
          },
        },
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawTicks: true,
          tickColor: '#94949E',
        },
        ticks: {
          color: '#1C3452',
          callback(value, index) {
            return index % 4 === 0 ? value : '';
          },
          font: {
            size: 16,
          },
          major: {
            enabled: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwpDf.png) is the model I am using where you will see what I am trying to do. Also, I am not familiar with chartjs so if I am missing some basics do not hesitate to tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have found a solution, for anyone interested in how :

By checking [this chart.js doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#common-options-to-all-cartesian-axes), you can find an option called offset which will create as explained an extra space.

Then to get the exact result I wanted, you hide the X axis.

Which gives us this :

```
x: {
    grid: {
        drawBorder: false, // hide the x axis
    },
},
y: {
    offset: true, // create a sensation of space with the x axis hidden
},
```