# Any way to make the y-axis border longer in chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

Any way to make the `y-axis` border longer on either side in chart.js?

**HAVE**

[image]

**WANT**

[image]

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#axis-range-settings

Answer (score 0):

While looking how to add padding between the tick marks and `x-axis`, I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67801140/space-between-ticks-marks-and-x-axis-with-chart-js) which allows me to do just that plus the above.

Which is by setting the `y` offset to true and hiding the `x` border:

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67801140/space-between-ticks-marks-and-x-axis-with-chart-js):

```
x: {
    grid: {
        drawBorder: false, // hide the x axis
    },
},
y: {
    offset: true, // create a sensation of space with the x axis hidden
},
```

In my case, it's enough.